# Heritrix: how to get more uri per sec on single domain?

Tags: java, spring, heritrix

how to get more uri/sec per domain with Heritrix 3.2.0? i already set the parallels option to max number like maxToeThreads and it still stays on 5 active threads at a single domain crawl in general.